# Assign value to collection from dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i need to assign value to collection from dictionary .  my sample code is below

```
public student
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set;}
}
```

and my dictionary collection is

```
Dictionary<string, Int16> StudentList= new Dictionary<string, Int16>();

StudentList.Add("Mahesh Chand", 35);
StudentList.Add("Mike Gold", 25);
StudentList.Add("Praveen Kumar", 29);
StudentList.Add("Raj Beniwal", 21);
StudentList.Add("Dinesh Beniwal", 84);
```

now my student collection will value only names list now i need to assign age to collection  based key name using linq without go for `foreach` , Is it possible in c# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, then you can initialize each student:

```
List<Student> students = AuthorList
    .Select(kv = > new Student{ Name  = kv.Key, Age = kv.Value })
    .ToList();
```

**Update**:

> I want to insert age in student collection depends on student
>   name , for that purpose i am using Name - Age dictionary collection as
>   lookup , is it clear?

Then you need some kind of loop, note that the Q in `LINQ` stands for query. It is not the right tool to update collections.

However, you can link both collections with LINQ efficiently using `Enumerable.Join` to prepare the `foreach`:

```
List<Student> allStudents = getYourStudents();
// link all known students in the name-age-dictionary with this collection:
var studentInfos = from s in allStudents
                   join sa in StudentList.Keys
                   on s.Name equals sa
                   select new { Student = s, Age = StudentList[sa] };
foreach (var s in studentInfos)
    s.Student.Age = s.Age;
```

Comment: I only need to assign age without creating new object like checking the name with key and assign value to collection if it is match the key because i will have some other property also in student class , now i modified my code sample  , student class contain another property like address

Comment: @Mahendran: assign `Age` to what? You haven't even shown a collection that contains `student`s. What is `AuthorList`?

Comment: i made mistake in my sample code , now i corrected it . i using some service which will give me the list of student with address and i will have local collection of student name with age , now i want add the age to above collection which contain name and address , this is my exact requirement

Comment: Now your sample is what i understood initially. In your last comment you didn't even mention a dictionary, it's difficult to understand the requirement.

Comment: Simply i want to insert age in student collection depends on student name , for that purpose i am using Name - Age dictionary collection as lookup , is it clear?

Comment: the above solution you have given is worked, i also achieved this using this code `allStudents.ForEach( student =>{ student.Age = StudentList[student.Name].ToString();  })`  , which one is better in performance , your solution or this one ?

Comment: @Mahendran: if the collection is large and the dictionary contains only a (small) subset of it the `Join` is more efficient since it uses a set under the hood (similar to a `HashSet`). But `allStudents.ForEach` or `foreach(Student s in allStudents)` should be fine under normal circumstances. I just wanted to fulfil your requirement: **"using linq"**

Comment: Btw, why does `student.Age = StudentList[student.Name].ToString();` compile when `Age` is an `int` property?

Answer (score 1):

```
var collection = dictionary.SelectMany(v => v.Value);
```

Comment: Error 3 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly